# Injecting javascript dynamically and using it

Tags: javascript

I also create a javascript file dynamically that uses those variables:

```
      function callbackF(data){
          console.log(data.script);

          document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].innerHTML=data.script;

        var script = document.createElement("script");
    script.setAttribute("src", "http://widget.example.com/sprk.1.0.2.js");
    script.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript");
    script.setAttribute("id", "grazit_script");
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
        }
```

This is what i get in my head:

This is what is printed to the console log:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>var dbnwid=16476; var dbnpid=23369; var dbnwebid=19720; var dbnlayout=21; var dbncolor='#000000'; var dbntitlefontsize='14'; var dbnbgcolortype=1; var dbnheader='You might enjoy reading:'; var dbnremindercolor=2; var dbn_protocol = (('https:' == document.location.protocol) ? 'https://' : 'http://'); </script>
```

and then the script:

```
<script src="http://widget.example.com/sprk.1.0.2.js" type="text/javascript" id="grazit_script"></script>
```

The second script should get the variables that are in the second script..but it doesnt..then it complains about why it doesnt get those variables

> UPDATE: 
>   Both of those ways below didnt work for me:

```
  eval(data.script);
           var ss= new Function(data.script)();
```

Comment: What is `#spark_static_widget`?

Comment: forget about it..i will edit my code again

Comment: Why have you accepted the answer if you say it doesn't work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because scripts run when they are loaded. Adding a `script` tag using `innerHTML` doesn't run the code inside the tag.

Comment: hmm..interesting answer.. is there a way for the external script to view the variables i put dynamically on the page?

Comment: Yes it does! Maybe not how OP's trying to accomplish it, but look at [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e7AAm/)

Comment: thats not what i try to accomplish read the answer that i updated now. couldnt i use eval()?

Comment: @MCL: No, it doesn't! The fiddle that you link to shows that code put inside a script element does run, but that's not what the OP is doing. Look at this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6c6Us/

Comment: @BlackFire27: Yes, using eval is one option. First you would remove the `script` tag from the string so that you have only the code, then you can either use `eval`, or put the code in an existing `script` element.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend using `eval()`. Another way would be `new Function('window.alert("hi")')();`

Comment: @MCL: Why would you not recommend using `eval` in this case?

Comment: I removed the script tags (By changing on the server), the eval didnt work for me.  eval(data.script);
           var ss= new Function(data.script)();

Comment: @Guffa I generally wouldn't recommend it because of the bad performance. Maybe it's not perceptible in this case, but using `new Function()` is equally easy to implement and is way faster.

Comment: @MCL: Actually, testing that in some different browsers shows that `eval` is not slow at all, but ranges from somewhat faster than `new Function()` to completely crushing it. http://jsperf.com/eval-vs-new-function-2